# Which of the following SQL statement should you use?

Tags: c#, sql, mta

I am brand new to C# and to stackoverflow.  I am reviewing questions that I got wrong on a prep test for my MTA certification.  Can anyone help me understand what the correct answer is and why?  Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2i4a.png)

Comment: A.. you need to check city and reference

Comment: sorry, but this isn't really a programming question... this is more "comprehensive reading" on a quite basic level

Comment: Yeah, you’re probably right. I just started learning programming and the SQL portion is especially intimidating to me. It goes to show that you can deduce some of these. Sorry for asking a silly question- just been overwhelmed heading into the test soon whether I’m ready or not because they are discontinuing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer would be A

Firstly it says update only those whose reference is TKY, all answers deal with that.

Secondly the updated region should be Japan, so that rules out B and C

Finally the update should only affect  customers in Tokyo, so that leaves only A since it's the only one of the four to limit the update with `and city='TOKYO'`.

Comment: Thank you!  I need to get my MTA cert to be admitted to the program and I am running out of time since they are discontinuing it!  I appreciate your help.  I am getting C# but it is somewhat slow going. Thank you!